# Show Line for Line From .InI file in Listview

Tags: c#, listview, ini

In my project I save customer informations ( username ,pass etc) in an ini file ( enccrypted ).
Like this:

```
WriteValue("Kunden", "Kunde", textBox3.Text);
WriteValue("Kunden", "Username", textBox1.Text);
WriteValue("Kunden", "Password", textBox2.Text);
```

This look like this in the finished Ini File:

```
[Kunden]
```

Kunde=test2

Username=aba

Password=1234

Ok Now I will Read this customer datas in a Listview like this:

```
         var kunde = ReadValue("Kunden", "Kunde");
        var username = ReadValue("Kunden", "Username");
        var password = ReadValue("Kunden", "Password");
        foreach (var customer in kunde)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(kunde + " " + username + " " + password);
        }
```

But I need for Every customer a sepperate Line with Name and password etc

Look whats my outgoing :
[image]

How can I make it for every customer I add ,a new line in the listview.
Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

1. In the design view add 2 more columns, so you should have 3 columns: Kunde, Username, Password
2. Add items to list view with the code (if you really wnat to show passwords in plain text):

.

```
listView1.Items.Add (new ListViewItem (new[] {kunde, username, password}));
```

Comment: thanks read my answer, but your examle helped me alot thanks :)